# Sending an email of a list for when things are edited in app script

Tags: arrays, loops, google-apps-script

[example form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5yb4.png)

I would like create an automated daily email that will the list style number & names when the style status column has been edited to "WFF".

Right now I have the following, but it only produces one style per email whereas I want one email with a list of the styles edited that day.

```
function sendEditNotification(e){

 if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.value != "WFF") return;

 const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,4).getValues();

 let email = "emailaddress@email.com";

 let styledescription = rData[0][3];

 let stylenumber = rData[0][2];

  let msg = stylenumber + " " + styledescription

 MailApp.sendEmail(email, "PROTO RCD", msg)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You broadly have 2 options there. Your current code is not unworkable but has downsides. Either way you will basically want to have some sort of buffer that you evaluate at the end (or start) of the day and send the email based on that.

Using your code as the basis the first option is to keep it as is, but instead of sending the value out right away you push it to an array in the properties. So something along the lines of

```
var scProps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
var messages = JSON.parse(scProps.getProperty('messages'));
messages.push(msg)
scProps.setProperty('messages',JSON.stringify(messages));
```

instead of your `MailApp.sendEmail(email, "PROTO RCD", msg)` would essentially store any edits into a sort of buffer. From there you can create a new function that reads the script property like the second line I gave in the example and then builds the message out of that array. After the new function sends the email you set the array to be empty.

**NOTE:** *this does have a serious possible downside that you can miss changes. For example if I were to change a value to WFF, but change my mind and change it back, this approach will still include that WFF change and not reflect what is on the spreadsheet at the time of sending.*

To mitigate that problem the other option would be to change your approach entirely and not care about individual changes. Instead you need to just use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet').getDataRange().getValues()` to get all the values (keep in mind this will include the header, otherwise you can use `getRange()` like you did in your code example to specify the  range, but it's more tedious) and store them in a property just like we did in option 1 by stringifying the array (*note that ideally you would create the property before the first run*).

Then what you do at the end of the day with a timed trigger is again, get the `dataRange()` values, then `JSON.parse` the values from the properties that you stored before and compare the 2 arrays. If it's a value that got changed to WFF then it goes into the message. Once the message is built and send out, you simply store the current spreadsheet values back into the property, overriding anything that was there on the day before.